# Exportar dados CSV via JS

Tags: javascript, csv, javascript-eventos

Tenho um conjunto de dados no banco de dados no meu *back end*, e preciso criar um botão na qual o usuário vai clicar para exportar esses dados em formato CSV. Mas nunca fiz esse tipo de *evento* no JS. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode criar um Ajax retornando de uma página PHP (ou outro script *back-end*) a lista de dados vinda do banco separados por vírgula e o usuário poderá fazer o download do arquivo `.csv`:

O JavaScript é este:

```
function baixar(){

   link_ = document.querySelector("#downloadcsv");

   if(link_){
      link_.outerHTML = '';
   }

   var http = false;
   http = new XMLHttpRequest();

   var url_="retorno.php";
   http.open("GET",url_,true);
   http.onreadystatechange=function(){
      if(http.readyState==4){
         var forma = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,";
         forma += http.responseText;

         // se quiser os valores separados por ; (ponto e vírgula)
         // substitua a linha acima por:
         // forma += http.responseText.split(",").join(";");

         var encoda = encodeURI(forma);
         var baixa = document.createElement("a");
         baixa.setAttribute("href", encoda);
         baixa.setAttribute("id", "downloadcsv");
         baixa.setAttribute("download", "arquivo.csv");
         document.body.appendChild(baixa);
         baixa.click();
      }
   }
   http.send(null);

}
```

Onde `retorno.php` é a página em PHP que irá retornar os dados do banco. Os dados retornados devem vir no formato abaixo:

```
dado1,dado2,dado3
```

E `arquivo.csv` é o nome do arquivo que será baixado.

Você deve criar um botão na página com o nome "Baixar arquivo" que irá chamar a função acima:

```
<input type="button" value="Baixar arquivo" onclick="baixar()">
```

Ou pode criar um link:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="baixar()">Baixar arquivo</a>
```

Comment: Fantástico... Muito obrigado!!

Comment: @MarcusBotelho Valeu! Considere marcar ✓ na resposta se achou útil. Abs!

Comment: Ajudou sim. Mais uma vez, obrigado!